# "This update is restricted" error when upgrading my system to High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, upgrade

I uninstalled Symantec from my work computer about a year ago but now that I am trying to upgrade it to High Sierra, I get this blocker:

[image: This update is restricted. Please install Symantec 14.0.3897.1101 before upgrading — OK]

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is not part of macOS, but rather is part of a 3rd party MDM (Mobile Device Management) solution that your administrator has installed on your computer. You should contact your administrator.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the correct answer :|